# Manually calculating PCA rotation using original data and PCA projections (scores)

Tags: r, pca

Is there any possibility of calculating PCA rotation similar to `R`'s `prcomp` function, by that I mean if I do the following

```
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir)$x
```

where `ir.pca` is a 150 by 4 (row by column) matrix, can I use this information to calculate rotation **without** using `prcomp(log.ir)$rotation`?

Comment: `Manually calculating rotation in PCA` Eigenvectors ("rotation") could be calculated by [arithmometer](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Arithmometer&num=30&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixyNz8mYrQAhVIiCwKHX2kAA4Q_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=833). I knew a guy many years ago who used to do complete PCA and factor analysis that way (saw him doing - rotating the reel, manually, and writing down results).

Comment: Perhaps my wording was not good, apologies for that. I'll change it so it is more clear for others.

Comment: WAKAS, your wording was perfect. I simply was joking (but I did know the guy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal components of your $N\times p$ (centered) data matrix $\mathbf{X}$ are given by
$$
\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X V}
$$
So you have that
$$
\mathbf{V}' = \mathbf Z'\mathbf X (\mathbf X'\mathbf X) ^ {-1}.
$$ 
You can compare the output of the second and third command:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100) # simulate some data
prcomp(X)$rotation
t(t(prcomp(X)$x) %*% X %*% solve(cov(X)))
```

Comment: I am interested in calculating using the information we obtain from 'prcomp(X)$x'

Comment: I modified my answer. Please be more precise the next time.